# putting if else clause in where condition sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I am a beginner and first time in sql procedure. If the user doesnt give any value to the parameter, it will return all the item. But I am trying to adding more where clause based on user input. I know there is if-else statement in sql procedure, but I have no idea if is it possible to append more condition.

Here is the statement

```
@FirstName varchar (50)
AS
SELECT distinct [user_identity], [first name], 
[last name], email, Name, orderdate,RenewalCount, RenewalDate

FROM 
db.[dbo].Users,
db.[dbo].[Order],
db.[dbo].[Subscription],
db.[dbo].[Products],
db.[dbo].[Order_Details]


WHERE 
db.[dbo].Users.user_identity = db.[dbo].Subscription.userid AND
db.[dbo].Users.user_identity = db.[dbo].[Order].userid AND
db.[dbo].[Order].Orderid = db.[dbo].[Order_Details].OrderId AND  
db.[dbo].Products.ProductId = db.[dbo].[Order_Details].Productid AND
db.[dbo].[Order_Details].OD_Id = db.[dbo].[Subscription].OD_Id



//if @firstname is not null and not empty
//append where clause condition
//AND db.[dbo].Users.[first name] = @FirstName
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So is it a question for SQL Server or MySQL? These are different things

Comment: Can't you do this with the language you are using to generate the SQL?

Comment: this is sql server stored procedure. @dotnetom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where condition should be like this:

```
WHERE 
db.[dbo].Users.user_identity = db.[dbo].Subscription.userid AND
db.[dbo].Users.user_identity = db.[dbo].[Order].userid AND
db.[dbo].[Order].Orderid = db.[dbo].[Order_Details].OrderId AND  
db.[dbo].Products.ProductId = db.[dbo].[Order_Details].Productid AND
db.[dbo].[Order_Details].OD_Id = db.[dbo].[Subscription].OD_Id AND
(@FirstName IS NULL OR @FirstName = '' OR db.[dbo].Users.[first name] = @FirstName)
```

Comment: the condition is working, thanks. But is it possible if I add 1 more condition Lets say @LastName?

Comment: The condition between brackets is just a separate condition, after that you can add as many conditions as you want

Answer (score 0):

append below condition in your where condition

```
where  @FirstName=case when isnull(@firstname,'')<>'' then db.[dbo].Users.[first name] else  @FirstName end
```